# Use wildcard for frontend rule in traefik configuration

Tags: docker, traefik

I try to run a traefik as proxy in front of my docker services.

To enable this i had to add for every service a frontend rule

```
docker service update --label-add traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.domain.com
```

Is it possible to use a wildcard for this? A domain is not always enabled in front of the traefik, it can also be only the ip address.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer:

```
# from my docker-compose.yaml service block
labels:
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{catchall:.*}"
  - "traefik.frontend.priority=1"
```

source:

https://www.techjunktrunk.com/docker/2017/11/03/traefik-default-server-catch-all/

Answer (score 1):

To enable wildcard certificates you have to:

- use the DNS Challenge
- define a section `[[acme.domains]]` in your traefik.toml.

```
[acme]
# ...
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.domain.com"
  sans = ["domain.com"]
# ...
```

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains

If a wildcard certificate is created for a domain (and SAN) by the `[[acme.domains]]` block, the certificate will be used for all frontend related to this domain (i.e. the frontend's rule won't create a dedicate certificate).

Comment: i think i my question was a bit wrong. i dont use acme and want only a rooting from *  to my service instead to say traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.domain.com